# Convert c# Graphics to ArcGIS ShapeFile

Tags: c#, gis, arcgis, shapefile

I have an application that gets some coordinates and draws some paths including that points in Panel with Graphics drawing tools.
Now I want to export this draw to an ArcGIS ShapeFile (*.shp) that ArcMap could open it as a layer.
Can any body help me?

Comment: you can ask this question on http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20848/is-it-possible-to-convert-graphics-to-features-in-arcgis-10-using-arcpy